# How to test NestJS Controller if it has a lot of dependent services?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs, ts-jest

I have a trouble with Testing Nest JS Controller because I cannot realise how to make a Testing Module with all the dependencies. I've already tried Mocks but still it's not working.
Here's how the controller I want to test looks like

**calculator.controller.ts**

```
@Controller('/calculator')
export class CalculatorController {
  constructor(
    @Inject(HISTORY_SERVICE)
    private historyService: HistoryService,
    @Inject(CACHE_SERVICE)
    private readonly cacheService: CacheService,
    @Inject(CALCULATOR_SERVICE)
    private readonly calculatorService: CalculatorService,
  ) {}
  @Get()
  getResult(@Query() expressionDto: ExpressionDto): Promise<ClientResponseDto> {
    const expression: string = expressionDto.expression;
    const response: Promise<ClientResponseDto> = this.cacheService
      .checkInCache(expression)
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response) {
          const calculationResult =
            this.calculatorService.getResult(expression);
          const clientDto = this.historyService
            .create({
              expression,
              result: calculationResult,
            })
            .then((dbResponse) => {
              return this.cacheService.setToCache(dbResponse);
            });
          return clientDto;
        }
        return this.historyService.create({ expression, result: response });
      });
    return response;
  }
}
```

And this is how it's spec looked like before mocks implementation

**controller.spec.ts**

```
let calculatorController: CalculatorController;
let calculatorService: CalculatorService;

beforeEach(async () => {
  const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [HistoryModule],
    controllers: [CalculatorController],
    providers: [
      CalculatorService,
    ],
  })
    .useMocker(() => createMock())
    .compile();
  calculatorController =
    moduleRef.get<CalculatorController>(CalculatorController);
  calculatorService = moduleRef.get<CalculatorService>(CalculatorService);
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});

describe('Calculator Controller', () => {
  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(calculatorController).toBeDefined();
  });
  it('should have all methods', () => {
    expect(calculatorController.getResult).toBeDefined();
    expect(calculatorController.getResult(calculatorStub().request)).toBe(
      typeof Promise,
    );
  });
});
```

And this test failed when calling `getResult` function cause inside this Function firstly I call CacheService to check data in Cache. So at this moment test failed telling that

```
TypeError: this.cacheService.checkInCache(...).then is not a function

      24 |     const response: Promise<ClientResponseDto> = this.cacheService
      25 |       .checkInCache(expression)
    > 26 |       .then((response) => {
         |        ^
```

I started to think that the problem is Testing module somehow doesn't have access to the Cache Service, so I added mock to the providers like this

```
let calculatorController: CalculatorController;
let calculatorService: CalculatorService;

beforeEach(async () => {
  const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [HistoryModule],
    controllers: [CalculatorController],
    providers: [
      CalculatorService,
      {
        provide: CacheService,
        useValue: {
          checkInCache: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(Promise<null>),
        },
      },
    ],
  })
    .useMocker(() => createMock())
    .compile();
  calculatorController =
    moduleRef.get<CalculatorController>(CalculatorController);
  calculatorService = moduleRef.get<CalculatorService>(CalculatorService);
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});
```

But now tests don't even run cause I have Nest dependencies problems

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CalculatorController (HISTORY_SERVICE, ?,

CALCULATOR_SERVICE). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [1] is 

available in the RootTestModule context.
```

What is the issue and how is it possible to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, when unit testing a service or a controller, you want to provide mocks for the controller's or service's dependencies. Most of the time, these are going to be *objects* with the same method names but the methods are set to be `jest.fn()` or similar for other mock libraries. You'll want to use [custom providers](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers) to create the mock providers that will be injected. Taking your controller above, you'll want the setup of your test to look something like this:

```js
describe('CaclulatorController', () => {
  let controller: CalculatorController;
  let service: Pick<jest.MockedObject<CalculatorService>, 'getResult'>;
  let cache: Pick<jest.MockedObject<CacheService>, 'checkInCache' | 'setToCache'>;
  let history: Pick<jest.MockedObject<HistoryService>, 'create'>;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const modRef = await Test.createTestModule({
      controller: [CalculatorController],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: CALCULATOR_SERVICE,
          useValue: {
            getResult: jest.fn(),
          },
        },
        {
          provide: CACHE_SERVICE,
          useValue: {
            checkInCache: jest.fn(),
            setToCache: jest.fn(),
          },
        },
        {
          provide: HISTORY_SERVICE,
          useValue: {
            create: jest.fn(),
          },
        },
      ]
    }).compile();

    controller = app.get(CalculatorController);
    service = app.get(CALCULATOR_SERVICE);
    cache = app.get(CACHE_SERVICE);
    history = app.get(HISTORY_SERVICE);
  });
```

Okay that's a lot to look at at once, so let's step through the big parts and explain what's going on here. The first this I do is set up local variables to reference during the test for the class that I'm testing (`CalculatorController`) and the dependencies of the class so I can modify them as necessary. Next, I use a `Pick<T, K>` generic with the `jest.MockedOject<T>` generic to tell Typescript that "This class has been mocked by jest, and I only am worried about these methods of it" so later on when I use `cache.` I'll get some intellisense for the `checkInCache` and `setToCache` methods, and they'll have jest's mock function types.

In the `beforeAll` I set up the initial mocks for the dependencies, you can also set return values here using the appropriate `mockReturnValue` or `mockResolvedValue` methods.

Now that the mocks and dependencies are set up, we can actually write a test. My approach is to use a `describe` block per method and `it`s per variation of the method's outcome and branches. I'll write a single branch to show you and let you work out the rest from there.

```js
  describe('getResult', () => {
    it('should get no response from the cache and perform a full caclulation', async () => {
      cache.checkInCache.mockResolvedValueOnce(undefined);
      service.getResult.mockResolvedValueOnce(calculationResult);
      histoy.create.mockResolvedValueOnce(dbResult);
      cache.setInCache.mockResolvedValueOnce(cacheSaveResult);
      await expect(controller.getResult({ expression: someExpression })).resolves.toEqual(cacheSaveResult)
    });
  })
```

This should cover the case where there's no value in the cache and the full set of steps has to be taken. By using `mockResolvedValueOnce` we ensure that the methods don't return if called more than once as that's most likely not the expected case here, and we're making sure to return promsies as you use `.then`s. You might want to look into `async/await` syntax to help clean that up.

putting the two snippets together we have the following:

```js
describe('CaclulatorController', () => {
  let controller: CalculatorController;
  let service: Pick<jest.MockedObject<CalculatorService>, 'getResult'>;
  let cache: Pick<jest.MockedObject<CacheService>, 'checkInCache' | 'setToCache'>;
  let history: Pick<jest.MockedObject<HistoryService>, 'create'>;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const modRef = await Test.createTestModule({
      controller: [CalculatorController],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: CALCULATOR_SERVICE,
          useValue: {
            getResult: jest.fn(),
          },
        },
        {
          provide: CACHE_SERVICE,
          useValue: {
            checkInCache: jest.fn(),
            setToCache: jest.fn(),
          },
        },
        {
          provide: HISTORY_SERVICE,
          useValue: {
            create: jest.fn(),
          },
        },
      ]
    }).compile();

    controller = app.get(CalculatorController);
    service = app.get(CALCULATOR_SERVICE);
    cache = app.get(CACHE_SERVICE);
    history = app.get(HISTORY_SERVICE);
  });

  describe('getResult', () => {
    it('should get no response from the cache and perform a full caclulation', async () => {
      cache.checkInCache.mockResolvedValueOnce(undefined);
      service.getResult.mockResolvedValueOnce(calculationResult);
      histoy.create.mockResolvedValueOnce(dbResult);
      cache.setInCache.mockResolvedValueOnce(cacheSaveResult);
      await expect(controller.getResult({ expression: someExpression })).resolves.toEqual(cacheSaveResult)
    });
  });
});
```

That should be enough to get you started on testing the rest of your controller. [If you need more test setup examples, there's an entire GitHub repository of them with different setups](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs)

Comment: Jay, thank you for support and help. I appreciated. But could you please provide a little bit more information regarding how it works inside the case. In the ```it()``` field you describe the scenario of dependent functions inside ```getResult``` as I understood. And when you call ```expect(getResult)``` we expect the function will follow the scenario which you described with mocks. But how can we test that some dependent functions inside ```getResult``` were not called for example?

Comment: You would need to change what the mocks return for the other `it`s in your test. ANd if you _really_ want to assert which branches are called you make use of jest's mock API and use things like `expect(cache.setToCache).not.toBeCalled()`